# OpsWorks Ruby returning nil for valid regex test

Tags: ruby, regex, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

In OpsWorks, I'm trying to test the number suffix on a hostname of a given node, and to extract that number if it isn't 1. If the number isn't 1, I have this regex to match the number:

```
/([\d]+)$­/
```

Which is run against a node naming scheme that follows this pattern:

- node1
- node2
- node3
- node(n...)

I've verified this works using Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/Ei0kqjaxQn

However, when I run this against an instance with OpsWorks, this match returns nil, no matter what number the hostname has at the end. The OpsWorks agent version is the latest at time of writing (4023), using Chef 12.13.37.

This is the code in the cookbook trying use the matched number:

```rb
short_app_name.to_s + node['hostname'][/([\d]+)$­/, 1].to_s + '.' + app['domains'].first
```

The run fails with type error `no implicit conversion of nil into String`. However, regex searches against that property work earlier in the recipe, when checking the node's number suffix. Is there a different method I should be using to extract the node's suffix?

---

Edit: `app['domains'].first` is populated. This line still fails with the same type error if it is swapped out with `domain.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy your regex and paste it into my terminal to test, there's a soft hyphen character after the dollar sign at the end of the regex, removing this makes things work:

The website isn't showing it even when I copy it from my terminal, but a screenshot shows the issue:

[image]

That second line ('irb(main):002:0') is what I copy/pasted from your cookbook code, the character is ["\xc2\xad"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00AD/index.htm)

Comment: Interesting. This isn't in my editor (VS Code), but I'll delete the expression and re-type it. Perhaps it snuck in there through some copypasta. I'll report back in a moment.

Comment: This was indeed the issue! Somehow, some invisible dash had made its way into my regex search. Is this character not being displayed in most places by design? If not, I might log a bug in the VS Code GitHub...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's not displayed by design or by accident, it might even just be a "not supported in this font" type deal.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the cookbook code and the error message, the problem may be that `app['domains']` is an empty array during the run. So you may want to verify that its value is correct.

Comment: This seems most likely to actually be causing the error they posted (since `nil.to_s` does return `""`), my answer deals with the other issues they asked about "this match returns `nil`", which also appears to be legitimate, just not error-causing

Comment: I can verify that `app['domains']` is populated. This also fails if I replace it with `domain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You error has nothing to do with the regex.
The issue is when you try to concatenate your existing `String` with

```
app['domains'].first
```

This is the only place this error would be raised because even if your `String#slice` returned `nil` you are calling `to_s` so it is an empty `String` but `String` + `nil` as would be the case if `app['domains'].first` is `nil` will raise this error.

breakdown

```
#short_app_name can be nil because of explicit #to_s
short_app_name.to_s 
####
# assuming node is a Hash
# node must have 'hostname' key 
# or NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass wil be raised
# node['hostname'][/([\d]+)$­/, 1] can be nil because of explicit #to_s
node['hostname'][/([\d]+)$­/, 1].to_s 
#####
# assuming app is a Hash
# app must contain 'domains' key and the value must respond to first
# and the first value must be a String or be implicitly coercible (#to_str) or it will fail with 
# TypeError: no implicit conversion of ClassName into String
# could explicitly coerce (#to_s) like you do previously  
app['domains'].first
```

Example:

```
node = {"hostname" => 'nodable'}
app = {"domains" => []}
node['hostname'][/([\d]+)$­/, 1]
#=> nil
node['hostname'][/([\d]+)$­/, 1].to_s
#=> ""
app["domains"].first
#=> nil
node['hostname'][/([\d]+)$­/, 1].to_s + '.' + app["domains"].first
#=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
node = {"hostname" => 'node2'}
app = {"domains" => ['here.com']}
node['hostname'][/([\d]+)$­/, 1].to_s + '.' + app["domains"].first
#=> "2.here.com"
```

Comment: The `.first` for `app['domains']` was to return the first item within it, as OpsWorks populates it like `"domains" : ["domain1.com", "domain2.com"]`

Comment: @TorpedoBench well it doesn't always. Sometimes it returns an empty array `[]` or atleast an array where `#first` returns `nil`. There is no other part of the code that would cause this error.

Comment: It seems like OpsWorks always has one value in that array, as the last item is always the short name of the app definition, even though it doesn't show this in the site's app definition page. You're correct, though, in that sometimes a method used on a data bag retrieved incorrectly will return `[]`. In this case, though, the issue was a hidden character inside the regex itself :)

Comment: @TorpedoBench that hidden character can not cause the error your reported `TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String` because hidden character or not `node['hostname'][/([\d]+)$­/, 1].to_s` will always be a `String` because you are explicitly converting it using `to_s`. This means at no point would `String` have to try an implicit conversion. When the error pops back up just remember my answer

Comment: This is the Chef log from a run that gave the type error after I removed `app['domains'].first`: `86>>     Chef::Log.warn("********** [#{cookbook_name}::#{recipe_name}] [DEBUGGING] With secondary naming regex, resulting DNS address is #{short_app_name}" + node['hostname'][/([\d]+)$­/, 1] + ".#{node['deployment']['zone_id']}.domain.com **********")`

Comment: Looks like I missed the `.to_s` for the regex search on this test, resulting in the type error. Sorry for the confusion!